# Add a comment in a sheet with PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying with this code to add a comment in a Excel cell :

```php
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment(($arr_periodes[2] + 1), 17 + ($arr_periodes[1]))
    ->setAuthor($user->prenom . ' ' . $user->nom);
$objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment(($arr_periodes[2] + 1), 17 + ($arr_periodes[1]))
    ->getText()
    ->createTextRun($res->commentaire);
$objCommentRichText->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment(($arr_periodes[2] + 1), 17 + ($arr_periodes[1]))
    ->getText()
    ->createTextRun("\r\n");
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment(($arr_periodes[2] + 1), 17 + ($arr_periodes[1]))
    ->getText()
    ->createTextRun($res->commentaire);
```

It opens file, but I need to repair it and comments doesn't show.

This is my writer :

```
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
```

**EDIT**

This code works :

```php
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment('E11')
    ->getText()
    ->createTextRun($user->commentaire);
```

Is it possible to put a variable in place of `'E11'` ?

I have to use `setCellValueByColumnAndRow`, thus `5,11` i.e.

**EDIT**

My problem persists :

I tried with this :

```php
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment(($arr_periodes[2]+1),(17+$arr_periodes[1]))
    ->getText()
    ->createTextRun($user->commentaire);
```

`($arr_periodes[2]+1)` contains in exemple `4`, and `(17+$arr_periodes[1])` contains in exemple `20`

The refernece is `4,17`

**The problem is that the first parameter has to be a letter !**

The file is only 17K and I have to repair it when I open it.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Are you using the correct writer? what excel version are you using? what writer and reader are you using? Also, are you pointing to a valid comment?

Comment: This is my writer : $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

Comment: Of course it's possible to put a variable in place of `'E11'`, it's just a standard PHP string, so can be replaced by a variable containing a PHP string like: `$cell = 'E11'; $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                            ->getComment($cell)
                            ->getText()->createTextRun($user->commentaire);`

Comment: If you have column and row numbers, then you can do `$cell = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(5-1) . 11;` to get `E11` from 5 and 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution :

I created an array :

```php
$arr_lettres = array(
    2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 4 => 'E', 5 => 'F', 6 => 'G', 7 => 'H', 8 => 'I',
    9 => 'J', 10 => 'K', 11 => 'L', 12 => 'M', 13 => 'N', 14 => 'O',
    15 => 'P', 16 => 'Q', 17 => 'R', 18 => 'S', 19 => 'T', 20 => 'U',
    21 => 'V', 22 => 'W', 23 => 'X', 24 => 'Y', 25 => 'Z', 26 => 'AA',
    27 => 'AB', 28 => 'AC', 29 => 'AD', 30 => 'AE', 31 => 'AF', 32 => 'AG'
);
```

And then :

```php
$objPHPExcel
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment( $arr_lettres[($arr_periodes[2]+1)].(17+$arr_periodes[1]) )
    ->getText()
    ->createTextRun($periodes->commentaire);
```

All is working now, I have my comments and text.

Comment: Why do people insist on re-inventing index numbers to letters functions when PHPExcel has it built-in..... $letterIndex = `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($numberIndex - 1)` as indicated in my comments

Comment: I reinvented it too!

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to the following recipe, and make sure you're using the Writer Excel2007.

[PHPExcel-Documentation-markdown-Overview-08-Recipes.md](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/dff9880582c4c379ffd4aee7dc62caaab2bab975/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#add-a-comment-to-a-cell)

> ```php
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
>     ->getComment('E11')
>     ->setAuthor('Mark Baker');
> $objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
>     ->getComment('E11')
>     ->getText()->createTextRun('PHPExcel:');
> $objCommentRichText->getFont()->setBold(true);
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
>     ->getComment('E11')
>     ->getText()->createTextRun("\r\n");
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
>     ->getComment('E11')
>     ->getText()->createTextRun('Total amount on the current invoice, excluding VAT.');
> ```

Comment: OK, this code works : $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getComment('E11')
    ->getText()->createTextRun('Total amount on the current invoice, excluding VAT.');  is it possible to change E11 by a variable please ?

Comment: getComment($cellIdentifier)->getText()...
But that has nothing to do with this question and is php basics.